# Hold up your time

Tags: grammaticality

During a call, a person mentioned that he is going to leave, I reply:

> "I wouldn't hold up your time as your family is waiting for you".

Is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Though grammatically correct, I think it is not idiomatic.

It is common to say:

> *Okay, I won't take your time (any more) as your...*

Though [*hold up*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hold-up) means *delaying something,* there are other usages as well that makes it a bit ambiguous in *this context.*

Comment: +1 Oh, and we usually put "anymore of" in there: *"Okay, I won't take anymore of your time"*. We also say *"Sorry, I didn't mean to hold you up"*